# Easiest paths from Pygame/PyOpenGL to iOS.

Tags: python, ios, pygame, game-engine

I have [a significant game](http://www.7grandsteps.com) I really need to port to tablets. (Android has PyGame subset for Android, which I'm still investigating). It would be great to take my Python code and move it to a more cross-platform engine.

I'm looking for engines with a pure code API, something I can wrap my intermediate glue for graphics and audio around. Kivy and some others use too much *ML (or JSON). Hoping I missed something good. The best I've seen is Futile for Unity3D, but Boo !!!!!= Python.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://ignifuga.org, it's Python based and inspired by projects like Cocos2d and AndEngine.

Comment: This could become a good option at some point, but its hopelessly lacking documentation, and its a very huge stack and involves a LOT of configuration which the OP seems uninterested in. Further, it appears to be either abandoned or moved somewhere private as there have not been any updates in quite sometime despite being unfinished. Shame. Honestly, I think someone just needs to take the plunge and port pygame or pyglet across to ios. Unfortunately my skill level dictates that I'm not that person :(

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on Ignifuga status.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Kivy framework](http://kivy.org/#home). I tried just some very simple demos but I can confirm that you can run it on PC/Mac/iOS.

Comment: is this still okay or the project has been abandonded?